# Training tensorflow network to check if two numbers are same doesn't work?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm new to python and tensorflow (and machine learning) and this is my first program. Once trained, it should accept two numbers and return [1, 0] if they're unequal and [0, 1] if they're equal.

I've modified the beginner tensorflow tutorial at https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/beginners (which looks for numbers in an image array) to this purpose. I train it on 1000000 pairs with both equal and unequal pairs with the numbers in [0, 100] range.

**Problems** - Training brings up the accuracy to 0.5 but no higher. Instead of returning [0, 1] or [1, 0], it returns [x, -x] (where x is a floating point number). I'm not sure if the problem lies in the python code or tensorflow usage but I suspect it is a silly beginner's mistake. What am I doing wrong?

Below is my code -

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 2])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 2])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2,2]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2]))
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
y = tf.matmul(x,W) + b
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.2).minimize(cross_entropy)(0.2).minimize(cross_entropy)#
xinput = [[1, 2], [4, 4]]
yinput = [[1, 0], [0, 1]]
for _ in range(0, 1000000): #Generates more random training data with a mix of equal and unequal pairs        
        temp = random.randint(0, 2)
        if(temp == 0):
            t1 = random.randint(0, 100)
            xinput.append([t1, t1])
            yinput.append([0, 1])
        else:
            t1 = random.randint(0, 100)
            t2 = random.randint(0, 100)
            if(t1 != t2):
                xinput.append([t1, t2])
                yinput.append([1, 0])
train_step.run(feed_dict={x: xinput, y_: yinput})
```

Then I test it with some test data -

```
xeval = [[1, 1], [2, 3], [5, 5], [34, 6]]
yeval = [[0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0]]
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: xeval, y_: yeval}))
```

Which always prints 0.5.

Here are the outputs of more variables -

```
print(y.eval(feed_dict={x: xeval, y_: yeval}))
Output - [[-0.0584463   0.0584463 ][-0.14445792  0.14445792][-0.289756    0.289756 ][-1.17759383  1.17759383]]

print(tf.argmax(y,1).eval(feed_dict={x: xeval, y_: yeval}))
Output - [1 1 1 1]

for var in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES):
    print('{0} - {1}'.format(var.name, sess.run(var)))
Output - Variable:0 - [[-0.02964323  0.02964323] [-0.0281842   0.0281842 ]]
Variable_1:0 - [-0.00061888  0.00061888]
```

Comment: How does the `cross_entropy` evolve during training? Perhaps try tuning the gradient descent parameters & use Momentum or Adam.

Comment: I'm actually completely at loss as to how to debug tensorflow and read graph's intermediate steps etc. Trying to figure out tensorboards etc. Thanks for the hints, I'll try to find read progression of cross_entropy. I tried Adam as well (for a slightly different input structure) but my accuracy is consistently low.

Comment: Yes, add a summary and view it in tensorboard, or just print the loss every few steps. If you reduce the amount of training data to a very small sample, it should get really good value (on the train data).